# Odoo Warning - Warning You are trying to install incompatible themes

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view

**Odoo Warning**
Odoo Warning - Warning
You are trying to install incompatible themes:
- Add to css (To be installed)
- Default Theme (Installed)

Please uninstall your current theme before installing another one.
Warning: switching themes may significantly alter the look of your current website pages!

this code i am trying

```
    <template id="styles_compiled" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend">
        <xpath expr="link[last()]" position="after">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/add_css_to_website/static/src/css/custom.css" />
        </xpath>
    </template>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Solution;
1. Please edit a file '**openerp**.py' (main directory) and change the line:.
'category' : 'Theme/Backend', with 'category' : 'Website',
2. Next, run 'Update Apps List' from developer mode.
3. Now you can install the theme.

thanks this is working for me... thanks